# Combine Powershell, AD and PHP

Tags: php, powershell

I want to create a PHP script that runs a PowerShell script based on the POST-DATA it gets.

Example link should be like this: localhost/query/index.php?GetUser=Username

This should result in PowerShell running following script with replcaing thhe username with the one received in POST.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity Username -Properties sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName,GivenName,Surname,title,company,department,co,proxyAddresses,mail,mobile,telephoneNumber,whenCreated,whenChanged,employeeNumber,extensionAttribute1 | Select-Object sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName,GivenName,Surname,title,company,department,co,proxyAddresses,mail,mobile,telephoneNumber,whenCreated,whenChanged,employeeNumber,extensionAttribute1,"End of userinfo" | Out-File -FilePath C:\xampp\htdocs\userinfo.txt
```

It can either be stored as .txt into another location, but preferable with result in the same PHP script. I have been able to run custom scripts from PHP using the code below, but then the PHP either has to create the script first as example "Temp.ps1" with the correct username to lockup based on the username in POST and then run the script and then delete the script

```
<?PHP
echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File ".\temp.ps1"');
?>
```

So based on the reply I received I tried to make it as basic as I could, and from the code below the PowerShell script/command is not using the variable I defined. The variable is visible in normal echo tho.

Final solution, thanks to ADyson

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Query User</title>
</head>
<body>

<?PHP
$username = $_GET['username'];
echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "Get-ADUser -Identity '.$username.' -Properties sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName,GivenName,Surname,title,company,department,co,proxyAddresses,mail,mobile,telephoneNumber,whenCreated,whenChanged,employeeNumber,extensionAttribute1 | Select-Object sAMAccountName,userPrincipalName,GivenName,Surname,title,company,department,co,proxyAddresses,mail,mobile,telephoneNumber,whenCreated,whenChanged,employeeNumber,extensionAttribute1"');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate all help

Comment: why not provide the username as a command-line argument to the powershell script?

Comment: Well, that's a good idea and I will try it that way. So I will run it with Username in the argument and then take the argument/username from the POST in PHP.

Comment: exactly. you can just inject the post value (having maybe sense-checked it a bit!) into the string of the shell_exec command.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it as simple as I could. Can you check my edited post and see if you have any solutions? PHP is not my strong language. Neither is Powershell

Comment: Since you're enclosing your PHP string in single-quotes it won't [interpolate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) the variable within the string...you'll need to concatenate it instead, i.e. `-Identity '.$username.' -Properties`. P.S. What I meant by sense-checking was just maybe to validate the data so as to avoid any potential for script injection of some kind (don't want users able to execute arbitrary powershell by accident...)

Comment: BTW you can still do this using the .ps1 script if you want...you just need to change that script to accept [input parameters](https://windows.tips.net/T002902_Passing_Parameters_to_a_PowerShell_Script.html)

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I forgot that I need to use '. .' enclosing. Yeah and regarding the Script injection I will add some checking to make sure it's a valid username I already have another script listing all the users. And for now, this page will only be on a closed network and used in WinForms (VB.net) so it won't be that easy for end-users to do any weird stuff. But I guess this is where I need to start learning web-developing so I can create these functions on an "admin portal" :) Appreciate your help!

Comment: Neither of the things you've mentioned would prevent users from doing something malicious, if they so choose (or if their machines are compromised without their knowledge). And anything could make a HTTP request to the PHP endpoint, not just the VB app

Comment: P.s. why not just get the vb app to talk to AD directly?

Comment: No, they won't if the user wants to they can. In this case, I'm really sure that it's not necessary as only a few domain-admins will be able to use this. The website will be locked to a specific custom UserAgent so website will be completely blank for users trying to browse it directly if they are even lucky enough to find the webpage. If you have any suggestion on "prevent script injection" feel free to tell. I would guess its for example to check if variable is string, do not contain any funny commands. Ect?

The company don't allow connecting directly to LDAP / AD

Comment: User agents can be easily spoofed. Better to have some actual authentication. Are you running PHP under IIS? P.s. yes that's what script injection prevention would be in this case - ensuring that the variable doesn't contain other executable code. If you Google powershell script injection you'll get much more advice than I can provide in a comment here. Also...maybe ensure the account which PHP (and therefore powershell) runs under doesn't have more domain privileges than it actually needs.

Comment: "The company don't allow connecting directly to LDAP / AD"... Really, so how do machines/users get authenticated when they log on to the network, then? They should at least be able to run net user USERNAME /domain from the command line. AFAIK you can't prevent that. Now the Active Directory Powershell tools may not be installed on clients by default but that's not the same as being unable to connect to AD. Any windows machine logged onto a domain-controlled network can connect to AD.

Comment: "if they are even lucky enough to find the webpage"...bots can find it easily enough. And you'd be surprised what curious users can do, too. But don't assume it's always humans who are attempting this. All kinds of nasty stuff could sneak into your network. Obscurity is not security. If you want to lock this down to domain admins then do so at the server level - i.e. secure the URL endpoint with appropriate Kerberos authentication and check the user's group membership before executing the script